# Unable to undo declined request to join

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

In the **Activity log** section of the group, I can see that **another** admin has declined a membership request, with the message:

```
{Admin} declined {Person's} request to join the group.  [See details] [Undo]
```

When click the **[Undo]** button, I get the message:

```
Approve member request?
{Person} will be added to the group
[Cancel] [Undo]
```

But when I click **[Undo]** here, it says `Activity undone` but the person is not added to the group, and I'm back to the start.

Any advice?